# missing some basic, issues casting strtok returns to other data types

Tags: c

Forgive the basic question, but i'm missing something foundational. Recently found myself having to code after 8 years of complete programming inactivity.

What i'm trying to do is read in a string (known amount of tokens within it), and then take these characters and convert them to integers.

This second part is my problem. I'm sure it's the way i'm handling the pointers,but am unsure exactly where i'm going wrong.

Any tips would be welcome, i'm sure there are several issues below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char str[] ="20\n3000 53\n96";
  char * pch;

  int num_one = 0;
  int num_two = 0;
  int num_three = 0;
  int num_four = 0;



  printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",str);
  printf("\n");
  pch = strtok (str," \n");
  num_one = atoi(&pch);
  printf ("%s\n",pch);  
  printf ("%u\n",num_one);   

  pch = strtok (NULL, " \n");
  printf ("%s\n",pch);  
  num_two = atoi(&pch);
  printf ("%u\n",num_two);  

  pch = strtok (NULL, " \n");
  num_three = atoi(&pch);
  printf ("%s\n",pch);  
  printf ("%u\n",num_three);  

  pch = strtok (NULL, " \n");
  num_four = atoi(&pch);
  printf ("%s\n",pch);  
  printf ("%u\n",num_four);      
  return 0;
}
```

Current output(can't get it to format correctly, but the \n are behaving as they should):

Splitting string "20 
3000 53
 96" into tokens:

20
0
3000
0
53
0
96
0

Comment: just correct `atoi(&pch);`  to `atoi(pch);`

Comment: enable compile warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly note that your string constants are const - you cannot modify them. strtok() will modify the calling string, so this can give rise to a GPF or core dump, unless you copy them.

I see you are calling atoi(&pch) which is incorrect - that should be atoi(pch); You gave it a pointer to a pointer to the string, and not a pointer to the string.

Comment: first argument is not string constant, `char str[] ="20\n3000 53\n96";`

Comment: this answer is correct, but first para is not required OP not passing string literal to strtok.

Comment: You are correct Grijesh - thank you for correcting me.

Comment: Really appreciate it guys. I guess i was trying to overly complicate it. Is there a better choice than atoi? I'd give you rep if i could.

Comment: I think another i had was incorrect (for anyone else who stumbles on this place like i did from google) was incorrect specification in print f(not using %s instead of any of the integer ones)http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Comment: As mentioned in another answer - sscanf() is a possibility - probably better to use. Doing strtok/atoi can be better if you want finer grained control of each argument and better error reporting. sscanf() will attempt to resolve all % arguments for you, but non-numerics or other strange input (eg comma separated numbers) or too many arguments require more work.

Answer (score 0):

This would probably be much simpler using [`sscanf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf), it will do it all in a single call.

Your format string would become something like `"%d %d %d %d"`, since newline is just whitespace to `sscanf()`.

If your input is "entrenched" you might also need to use `%n` to figure out many characters of input were consumed. This is helpful to skip to the next "record". Also remember to check the return value to know whether the call suceeded or not.